# C# code to access VMware vSphere PowerCLI

Tags: c#, vmware, powercli

Are there examples of C# code accessing vSphere API through PowerCLI or otherwise? For test automation, is PowerCLI script or C# code calling vSphere API the better choice? Please advise on docs and examples

Answer (score -1):

Here are C# samples for the web services API: http://communities.vmware.com/community/developer/codecentral/vsphere_ws_c

And here is the programming guide for using C# with the .NET assemblies that come with PowerCLI: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40/doc/viwin_devg.pdf

On a personal note, I prefer PowerCLI for doing my test automation. Lots of things can be accomplished with one line of PowerCLI, and you never have to open Visual Studio. ;)

Comment: We have libraries at work that allow us to easily inject powershell scripts into our C# code.  This allows us to leverage or SysEng types who already have scripts to do things.

Comment: I would be very interested in exploring options to inject powershell scripts into C# code. Can you share some approaches/samples please?

Comment: @JakeRobinson: Jake is it possible to automate the execution of a PowerCLI script? For example can I execute the PowerCLI script via C# code or some other automated process/way?