# Scripting using powerCLI Scripts

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, virtualization, powercli

Is it possible to do scripting using powerCLI scripts to automate VM creation using notepad? or any powerCLI developing tool?

How to go about studying PowerCLI scripting from scratch to automate VM creation?

Comment: I just create a PowerCli tag in StackOverflow, and I retag your question. I also retag [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478868/c-code-to-access-vmware-vsphere-powercli)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More or less two months ago, I started learning powershell because the needing of using PowerCLI :). PowerCLI is the best choice for scripting vmware vsphere automation.

When you start PowerCLI command line tool you can work there exactly as you were inside the powershell. Furthermore, you can use all the included cmdlets (more than 200) for vmware vsphere automation.

Scripting with PowerCLI is exactly the same as scripting with Powershell. Try it!

To get started:

- [Getting Started](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-13700)
- [PowerCLI home](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli)
- [Community Discussions](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli?view=discussions)
- [Online Reference](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/index.html)

---

**NOTE**
You won't find here at stackoverflow a lot of answerers about PowerCLI (I think and, anyway, unless me and someone other). The fact that @JPBlanc as created a new tag about it is a proof. If you really want support in your scripting questions go directly to the vmware community, you will find everything there.

---

**NOTE ABOUT NOTEPAD**

DO NOT USE NOTEPAD. Use something like Powershell ISE or VIM or Notepad++.

Comment: @JPBlanc: Initially I was interested in, but never had the chance (and the need) of installing it. I'm perfectly able to do scripting without that. Anyway it's a good choice indeed, a thing to try.

Comment: really just try it. Except if you use a commercial one/

Comment: @JPBlanc: I'm using just ISE and VIM. And also I normally execute scripts from the console directly. But thanks, I will definetely.

Answer (score 0):

@JPBlanc I use PowerGUI Script Editor and it works great.  Make sure to add it to your sendto folder so you can just drop highlighted scripts right into the editor.